# Get color of arc in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I have drawn many colourful arcs and they are revolving around a ball. when user touches the screen the ball shoots in the direction of its pointer.
now i want to get color of arc with which it is colliding when the collision occurs.
Please help..
sample image is this: 
[image]

I want to get output in RGB format or hash format or in any known format by which i can use it for comparison.

Please any suggestions would be helpful...Thanks in advance..

Comment: Need more info...how are you drawing the arcs? How are you detecting collisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't simply treat each arc as a separate instance with the color stored in a field?

```
 public class Arc
 {
    //color stored in the arc for easy retrieval
    public Color myColor = new Color(...);

    public void update()
    {
        //make the arc do everything the original arc was supposed to do
        //such as rotate, get drawn to the screen, etc
    }

    //One of many ways to retrieve the color during a collision
    public Color testCollision(Ball b)
    {
       if (/* Ball is colliding with arc */) return myColor;
       else return null;
    }
 }
```